# SQL (Snowflake) - Column that recursively refers to itself

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have seen a number of posts on this topic but I couldn't find any that are exactly the same.

I would like to make a view with a column that refers to itself. In the example below:

- Value 1 + 2 are static values that continue throughout the view.
- Value 3 has data that updates so I want it to do Value 3 + (Value 1 - Value 2) when there is data in Value 3.
- When Value 3 has no data, use it's prior value to calculate.

| Index | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | Calculation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.5 | 0.25 | 1 | 1.25 |
| 2 | 0.5 | 0.25 |  | 1.5 |
| 3 | 0.5 | 0.25 |  | 1.75 |

Is this possible? So far I have got it to calculate the row where index = 2 using LAG or Recursive CTE's but can't seem to work out how to get it to continue calculating.

Comment: You ether need to use a recursive CTE which has an hard limit on looping. Or a UDTF to carry state for you. I would use that latter.

Comment: Actually if index is present and v2 & v1 are static then you can use lag ignore nulls to  carry v3 and use linear extrapolantion of v1-v2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With slightly extended example data to show a new value3 taking precedent:

```
WITH data(Index, Value1, Value2, Value3) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES   
    (1, 0.5, 0.25,  1),
    (2, 0.5, 0.25,  null),
    (3, 0.5, 0.25,  null),
    (4, 0.5, 0.25,  10),
    (5, 0.5, 0.25,  null),
    (6, 0.5, 0.25,  null),
    (7, 0.5, 0.25,  null)
)
select d.*
    ,iff(d.value3 is not null, d.index, null) as idx_k
    ,lag(d.value3) ignore nulls over(order by d.index) as l_value3
    ,lag(idx_k) ignore nulls over(order by d.index) as l_idx_k
    ,d.index - iff(idx_k is not null, idx_k, l_idx_k)+1 as r_d
    ,iff(d.value3 is not null, d.value3, l_value3) + r_d*(d.value1-d.value2) as calc
from data as d
order by 1;
```

gives:

| INDEX | VALUE1 | VALUE2 | VALUE3 | IDX_K | L_VALUE3 | L_IDX_K | R_D | CALC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.5 | 0.25 | 1 | 1 |  |  | 1 | 1.25 |
| 2 | 0.5 | 0.25 |  |  | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1.5 |
| 3 | 0.5 | 0.25 |  |  | 1 | 1 | 3 | 1.75 |
| 4 | 0.5 | 0.25 | 10 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 10.25 |
| 5 | 0.5 | 0.25 |  |  | 10 | 4 | 2 | 10.5 |
| 6 | 0.5 | 0.25 |  |  | 10 | 4 | 3 | 10.75 |
| 7 | 0.5 | 0.25 |  |  | 10 | 4 | 4 | 11 |

which can be smashed together into:

```
select d.*
    ,iff(d.value3 is not null, d.value3, lag(d.value3) ignore nulls over(order by d.index)) + (d.index - iff(d.value3 is not null, iff(d.value3 is not null, d.index, null), lag(iff(d.value3 is not null, d.index, null)) ignore nulls over(order by d.index))+1)*(d.value1-d.value2) as calc
from data as d
```

if you really want, but I would be more inclined to wrap that in a sub-select just to make it present nicer:

```
select index, value1, value2, value3, calc 
from (
    select d.*
        ,iff(d.value3 is not null, d.index, null) as idx_k
        ,lag(d.value3) ignore nulls over(order by d.index) as l_value3
        ,lag(idx_k) ignore nulls over(order by d.index) as l_idx_k
        ,d.index - iff(idx_k is not null, idx_k, l_idx_k)+1 as r_d
        ,iff(d.value3 is not null, d.value3, l_value3) + r_d*(d.value1-d.value2) as calc
    from data as d
)
order by 1
```

### Recursive CTE:

```
WITH recursive r_cte as (
    select index, value1, value2, value3, value3 as calc
    from data 
    where index = 1
    
    union all
    
    select d.index, d.value1, d.value2, d.value3, iff(d.value3 is null, r.calc, d.value3) + d.value1 - d.value2 as calc
    from r_cte as r
    join data d on r.index + 1 = d.index
)
select * from r_cte
```